# How to remove only Total Tax from invoice pdf?

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, pdf, totals

I am using Magento 1.9.3

I have enabled **Display Full Tax Summary** and its working fine. I can see my VAT and TAX both in totals area.

But now I need to remove only **Total Tax** data from invoice PDF. (*Screenshot*)

Is it possible to remove **Total Tax** data only form PDF?

[image]

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override this file

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php

to

> app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php

and Find **insertTotals** function

```
foreach ($total->getTotalsForDisplay() as $totalData) {
    $lineBlock['lines'][] = array(
        array(
            'text'      => $totalData['label'],
            'feed'      => 475,
            'align'     => 'right',
            'font_size' => $totalData['font_size'],
            'font'      => 'bold'
        ),
        array(
            'text'      => $totalData['amount'],
            'feed'      => 565,
            'align'     => 'right',
            'font_size' => $totalData['font_size'],
            'font'      => 'bold'
        ),
    );
}
```

to

```
foreach ($total->getTotalsForDisplay() as $totalData) {
                    if($totalData['label'] != "Tax:") {
                    $lineBlock['lines'][] = array(
                        array(
                            'text'      => $totalData['label'],
                            'feed'      => 475,
                            'align'     => 'right',
                            'font_size' => $totalData['font_size'],
                            'font'      => 'bold'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'text'      => $totalData['amount'],
                            'feed'      => 565,
                            'align'     => 'right',
                            'font_size' => $totalData['font_size'],
                            'font'      => 'bold'
                        ),
                    );
                     }
                }
```

Comment: Dear Rakesh, worked but I had to update the app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: what update ? app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php.

Comment: Same code you shared.

Comment: you want to remove also above tax also? i don't understand

Comment: Rakesh: Code you shared dose the exact thing what I needed. I am just saying that I had to change in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php file instead of app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php. 
Please accept the edit.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand mate what you want here please update more clear again

Comment: You told me copy app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php and to update insertTotals function. But when I tried after updating in copied file it was not working. It worked when I updated in insertTotals function of app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php

Comment: Hope you understood what I am trying to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90979/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-sa-soibal).